# Is there a way to set what * means in a linear algebra library?

Tags: eigen, blas, eigen3

I have two dense matrices M,N, and I want to calculate M*N, BUT instead of using regular multiplication when operating on the elements, I want * to denote taking the minimum of the two (but + is still additon)

For example, if

```
M =  
(1 2) 
(3 4)
```

Then

```
M*M  =
(1+2 1+2)
(1+3 2+4) 
=
(3 3)
(4 6)
```

because according to how dot product is performed, (1 2)*(1 3) = min(1,1) + min(2,3) = 1 + 2, and so on.

Is this at  all possible? Perhaps there is template class where binary operation * is defined or something?

Thank you.

Edit: As suggested, I tried defining my own scalar type, but it doesn't work.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;

struct my_scalar
{
    my_scalar(double a = 0.0) : value(a) {} 
    operator double&() { return value; }
    operator double() const { return value; }
    double value;
};

using Matrix = Eigen::Matrix<my_scalar,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic>;

inline my_scalar operator*(const my_scalar& x, const my_scalar& y)
{
    return my_scalar(min(x.value,y.value));
}

inline my_scalar operator+(const my_scalar& x, const my_scalar& y)
{
    return my_scalar(x.value+y.value);
}

inline my_scalar operator-(const my_scalar& x, const my_scalar& y)
{
    return my_scalar(x.value-y.value);
}

int main()
{
    Matrix A(2,2);
    A(0,0) = my_scalar(1);
    A(1,0) = my_scalar(3);
    A(0,1) = my_scalar(2);
    A(1,1) = my_scalar(4);
    cout << "A = " << endl << A << endl;

    cout << "A*A = " << endl << A*A << endl;
}
```

The output is that A*A is a matrix with four 1's!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your own scalar type with all arithmetic operators defined as you like. Then, plugin it into Eigen's matrices, i.e., 'Matrix', and your done. The down side is that you will loose explicit vectorization.

**EDIT:**

To make sure it will work as expected, you must be careful because Eigen's matrix product implementation sometimes assume that `1` is the multiplicative identity which is not the case for you. This path of code is enabled to optimize large enough matrix product, so you can use `A.lazyProduct(B)` to always follows the simple matrix product path which never makes such an assumption.

Comment: It didn't work ;(. It took me a while, but after defining my own scalar type with my own multiplication, if I multiply the matrices as in the example, I get a matrix filled with 1's...

Comment: See my original post for an example.

Comment: Your example works for me with Eigen 3.3, I get `[3 3;4 6]`.